# Limit of $ \frac1{n -\log n}$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am not able to find the following limit.
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n-\log n}$$

I tried replacing log function with it's expansion but soon stuck.
Also tried dividing both numerator & denominator by $n$ to get the following
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1-\frac{\log\ n}{n}}$$ 
but couldn't proceed further. 
Can I break the numerator & denominator into $2$ separate limits ?
Please also suggest how to calculate this limit? (You can replace $n$ by $n+1$ here)

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that:

$$\frac{1}{n-\log n}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\log n}{n}}\to 0\cdot 1=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Note that we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{n} = 0$, you can prove that using L'hopital's rule and you can use that to answer your question.

Comment: But that would require separating limits of numerator & denominator & considering them as 2 separate functions. Can we do that?

Comment: [check here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitsProperties.aspx) point $4$. check the limit of the denominator is non-zero.

Comment: thanks ! Just 1 more clarification reqd. Assume a case, where I have to find limit of f(x)*g(x) .If separately calculated, limit of f(x) comes out as infinity & that of g(x) as 4. Can we say f(x)*g(x) tends to infinity

Comment: yes, when $x$ is huge, $f(x)g(x) \geq f(x)$, hence the result.

Comment: This is confusing. How can we separately calculate limits of f(x) & g(x) when limit of f(x) doesn't exist (i.e. it is infinite). ?

Comment: it means $f$ gets arbitrarily large as $x$ goes to $\infty$, hence $f(x)g(x)$ as an upper bound has to be arbitarily large as well.

Comment: Technically L'H can't be used here since these are sequences. But you can you L'H to prove a stronger statement about the function f defined on (0,inf) given by f(x) = ln(x)/x. Then as a consequence you'll get that the sequences approaches 0 as well

Answer (score 0):

Using equivalents for large $n$ (remembering that $\log(n)< n)$ $$\frac{1}{n-\log (n)}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\log (n)}{n}}\sim \frac{1}{n}\left(1+\frac{\log (n)}{n} \right)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\log (n)}{n^2}$$